# Link back to App using FBDialogs

Tags: ios, facebook, ios7, fbdialogs

FBDialogs presentations can have a link as NSURL and picture as NSURL as parameters.
But how to make clicking the post on the mobile to link back to iOS App if installed (to AppStore if not) and to some web page when accessed from the browser?

I've got the URL scheme of fb[app_id] set. What to do next? How to use it to launch my app when clicking the post?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you turn on deep linking in your app settings on facebook?

Comment: Yes. But what should I pass to FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink: name: caption: picture: in the link parameter? How clicking the post that shares some link will open my iOS app?

Comment: You can pass any link, but it should be a link that you want to distribute. As an example, if you are the New York Times app, you'd probably want to put in a nytimes.com url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will answer myself the question.
What was missing in my understanding, is that clicking the post from a web will open the link that I share with - FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink: name: caption: picture:, whereas clicking it on iPhone will open my app and not that link, if deep linking is turned on in FB's app settings.

Answer (score 1):

add this method in appdelegare class

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I have it, but when does it fire? Who launches fb[app_id]://?

Comment: What NSURL parameters should I pass to FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink: name: caption: picture: so that that link opens my app?

Comment: you pass your sharing url

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. Could you please clarify? I want to share for example cnn.com. If this is the sharing URL I pass, how my app is launched?

Comment: read this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share-dialog/ it provide all info.